# What preposition should I use here "Can you change a $20 note _____ two $10 notes"?

Tags: prepositions, idiomatic-language

What preposition should I use in the blank?

> Can you change a twenty-dollar ($20) note _____ two ten-dollar ($10) notes?

Comment: The most common preposition here is probably ***for***, but ***into*** is also fine, and just ***to*** is at least "acceptable". More colloquially, *Can you **break** a 20$ note into two tens?* (most people wouldn't bother repeating ***notes*** or ***dollars***, and it's incorrect to actually write out the word ***dollars*** after a value that includes the dollar sign $).

Comment: The dollar sign should also precede the figures, i.e. $20, not 20$.

Comment: The word "bill" would probably be used instead of  "note", although spoken usage would omit that too: Can you change a twenty for two tens?

Comment: I'm not sure that's true outside North America, @JackO'Flaherty.  Searching the GloWBe corpus for "five/ten/twenty/fifty dollar bill/note" has 56:8 (bill:note) for the US and 19:0 for Canada, but 2:6 for Australia and 4:9 for NZ: not big  numbers, I accept, but differently skewed.

Comment: @ColinFine Interesting. I forgot how widely 'dollar' is used.

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate preposition is **for**:

> Can you change a twenty-dollar ($20) note **for** two ten-dollar ($10) notes?

This is the idiomatic way of asking for money to be *exchanged*.

Some people *might* use "into", but technically that is wrong. Changing something *into* something else means to *transform* it so that it becomes something new. For example, a tadpole *changes into* a frog.

Comment: On what authority do you assert that _into_ is "technically" wrong? I shall have to remember never to change into another pair of shoes, since Astralbee thinks that I will thereby become a pair of shoes.

Answer (score 1):

A very idiomatic way to say this is:

Could you change this twenty for two tens?

No need to qualify it with bill or note or even dollars.